# how to define case and control in NRI calculation with nricens packages using R?

Tags: statistics, prediction, evaluation

**I am trying to calculate the NRI for time- event model by using nricens packages in R.

the codes are like this.
**

`nricens(mdl.std = mstd, mdl.new = mnew, t0 = 10, cut = c(0.05, 0.1),updown = "category", niter = 1000,alpha = 0.05)`

**the results show this,**

[image]

so my question is the total number is 3017, the case number is 125, and the control number is 1331. where are the other participants go? or what are the criteria to define case/control in such a situation?

Thank you all very much.

I have tried to read some references and the explanation  of this package, but could not find the answer that I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

According to my own experience, I think the 'nricens' automatically removes the controls with survival time < t0.